# setTimeout in loop to check for a change in bounds

Tags: javascript, google-maps, while-loop, settimeout

This is my code:

```
var b;
while(!b){
    setTimeout(function(){
        alert('sss')
        b=1;
    }, 500);
}
```

and it will not alert 'sss'

What can i do?

**Updated:**

I want to get bounds on google maps v3:

```
function get_bounds(){
            var bounds_;
            while(!bounds_){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    bounds_=map.getBounds();
                    if(bounds_){
                        var leftBottom=[bounds_.getSouthWest().lat(),bounds_.getSouthWest().lng()]
                        var rightTop=[bounds_.getNorthEast().lat(),bounds_.getNorthEast().lng()]
                        return [leftBottom,rightTop];
                        }
                }, 500);
            }
        }
```

**updated2:**

hi patrick dw, i don't know why , but your code doesn't work:

```
var b;
function waitForB() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(!b)
            waitForB();
        else
            alert('sss');
    }, 500);
}
waitForB()
```

**updated3:**

it is ok now :

```
var b;
function waitForB() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(!b){
            waitForB();
            b='ss';
        }
        else{
            alert('sss')
        }
    }, 500);
}
waitForB()
```

Comment: You forgot a semicolon after alert(...)

Comment: Yes that's true, but semicolons are not always mandatory in Javascript.

Comment: @Radomir: Thanks to JavaScript, the `;` won't actually make a difference. JS will assume a newline as a line delimiter in the absence of a `;` or not being in a `(...)` block.

Comment: If you're just trying to run the code every `500ms` until you get `bounds_`, see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript in web browsers is run in a single thread. When you call `setTimeout()`, it won't spawn a new thread. This means that `setTimeout()` will not execute until all of your main code has finished executing.

For this reason, you will end up with an infinite loop, because your loop condition is dependant on the execution of the `setTimeout()` callback.

Here's an interesting article on how JavaScript timers work:

- [How JavaScript Timers Work](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) by John Resig

---

**UPDATE:**

Further to the updated question, you may want to listen to the `bounds_changed` event instead. I am not sure how you are planning to use your `get_bounds()` function, but you may want to refactor your logic to use an event listener instead:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'bounds_changed', function () {
   // The code here is triggered when the bounds change
});
```

Comment: hi Daniel, look the updated, i want get the bounds of google maps v3, but some times i can't get it , so i have to get it sometimes later, so  what can i do about it ..

Comment: @zjm1126: Why don't you listen to the `bounds_changed` event? `google.maps.event.addListener(map,'bounds_changed', function () { });`

Comment: Can you summarize the interesting linked article in your answer? It protects the ideas from link rot.

Answer (score 1):

That code is going to burn CPU time and memory by scheduling timeouts to happen. Think about it: you're loop condition is "b" becoming truthy.  How is that going to happen?  Only when a timer event fires. Will that happen?  No, because you're eating the whole machine scheduling zillions more timeouts.

This sort of situation has as a tell-tale sign the effect of warming up the room you're sitting in.

I don't know what effect you're trying to get. Why not start by *just* the `setTimeout()` call and see how that goes. Maybe you could describe more about what it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will want to use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`.
When `b` is changed, alert shows up.

```
var b = false;
(function () {
    var intervalId;
    function wait() {
        if (b) {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
            alert('sss');
        }
    }
    intervalId = setInterval(wait, 500);
})();
```

It is more intuitive and it doesn't mess with global variables too much.

HINT: Put semicolon after every statement if you are not sure where to omit safely.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can now be solved correctly using the `idle` rather than the `bounds_changed` event listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() { 
  updateStuff();
});
```

*This event is fired when the map becomes idle after panning or zooming.*
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html

It also fires after the map is first rendered, so this is probably the only event listener you need on your map in order to keep it up to date.